# Android studio: How to artificially display a webpage?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want to show the html file stored in localstorage when I access a webpage using chrome without being connected to the internet.

For example, if you try to access https://google.com without being connected to the Internet

```
<p>google.com</p>
```

I want the above html code to be displayed.

How can I perform the above tasks using android studio?

*(My native language is not English. Please forgive me if the sentence is awkward)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code inside activity

```
 WebView wv;  
 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html");
```